# .NET build error

Tags: subsonic

Having added the subsonic 2.2 subcommander sonic.exe as an external tool I can generate my DAL classes in my defined \dataaccess\generated\ folder but when I build the project I get an error in the following file:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\subsonictest\bdf9ac02\aff68c1c\App_Code.2ygn7ole.0.cs in the following:
```

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an object wrapper for the iData_sp_GenerateDataSQL Procedure
/// </summary>
public static StoredProcedure IDataSpGenerateDataSQL(string TABLE, string IDENTITYCOL)
{
  SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = new 
      SubSonic.StoredProcedure("iData_sp_GenerateDataSQL", 
                               DataService.GetInstance("KLA"), 
                               "PUZZLE\mnolan");        
  sp.Command.AddParameter("@TABLE", TABLE, DbType.AnsiString, null, null);       
  sp.Command.AddParameter("@IDENTITYCOL", IDENTITYCOL, DbType.AnsiString, null, null);
  return sp;
}
```

The error message is - `error CS1009 Unrecognized escape sequence` and shows the error is associated with the PUZZLE\mnolan string.
I can escape the sequence with '\' but this won't help because this is a temporary build file and is regenerated.

Thanks for the help,

Mike

Comment: What is the "PUZZLE\mnolan" string referring to?

Comment: @geofftnxz - I think that's the login for the schema, but not sure why subsonic doesn't already escape or `@""` it.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

> @"PUZZLE\mnolan"

Backslashes are special characters in C# strings.  The @ tells C# to treat them literally.  You could double the backslash instead.

Comment: Yeah PUZZLE\mnolan is my login to the puzzle domain used to login to the PC used for the build. I have tried the @ prefix and the \\ with same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  You'll either have to fix the tool that generates the code or post-process it with a scripting tool like Windows Powershell or python before compiling it.

Comment: I have removed the sp [PUZZLE\mnolan].[iData_sp_GenerateDataSQL] that was causing the issue (it is not required) and the build now fails in the temp file App_Code.mbu5qmhf.0.cs at:

public KLA.FavouriteCollection Favourites()
  {
   return new KLA.FavouriteCollection().Where(Favourite.Columns.ProductID, ProductID).Load();
  }
with error CS0117 - bool does not contain a definition for columns. This is in the ActiveRecord class which wraps the Products table.
Is this a problem with the Products schema?